# Solving integer quadratic program related to combinatorial optimization

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, discrete-optimization

I need to find the solution for a combinatorial optimization problem which I reformulated into the following Integer Quadratic Program:

Given

- a family of $p$ integers $\{c_1,...c_p\}$
- and a $n\times n$ matrix $A$ with nonnegative entries and a null diagonal,

Find a family of $p$ binary vectors $(I_{P_k})_{1\le k\le p}$ which maximizes:
$$\sum_{k=1}^p \  ^t I_{P_k}A I_{P_k} $$
Subject to
$$\left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
\displaystyle\forall k\in [|1,p|], \ \  %(1,1,...1) P_k=
\sum_{i=1}^n (I_{P_k})_i=c_k \\
\displaystyle  \sum_{k=1}^p I_{P_k}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ \vdots \\ 1\end{pmatrix}
\end{array}
\right.
 $$
 Note that all sums are computed with the usual, not binary addition.

Comment: What do you mean by "defined positive matrix A with a null diagonal"?   If $A$ is a symmetric matrix with $A_{i,i}=0$ for $i=1$, $2$, $\ldots$, $n$, and $A$ is positive semidefinite, then $A=0$.

Comment: A quadratic form $x^TAx$ can be linearized if $x$ is binary. So you can formulate this as a linear MIP. Works whether convex or not.

Comment: Actually I didn't reallly check whether the matrix was positive definite; it has nonnegative values and a null diagonal.

Comment: can you tell me how the quadratic form can be linearized? I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The objective function in your model can be rewritten as:
$$ \sum_k v_k^T A v_k $$ 
Let's just look at one term:
$$ z = x^TAx = \sum_{i,j} a_{i,j} x_i x_j$$
where $x_i\in\{0,1\}$. 
We can replace $y_{i,j}=x_i \times x_j$ using:
$$\begin{align}
 &z = \sum_{i,j} a_{i,j} y_{i,j}\\
 &y_{i,j} \le x_i\\
 &y_{i,j} \le x_j\\
 &y_{i,j} \ge x_i + x_j - 1\\
 &x_i, y_{i,j} \in \{0,1\}
\end{align}$$
This is now completely linear.

Note: this is a tight formulation. We can relax $y$ to be continuous between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: can you explain your "note" in more detail? What does "tight" mean, and why does it imply that we can relax $y_{i, j} \in [0, 1]$?

Comment: Compare with an alternative formulation: $y_{i,j}\le \frac{x_i+x_j}{2}$, $y_{i,j}\ge x_i+x_j-1$. This one is not as tight. The relaxed point $(x_i,x_j,y_{i,j})=(0,1,1/2)$ is infeasible for the original formulation but feasible for this one.